# Taylor polynomial/ remainder

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, taylor-expansion

I need to calculate the Taylor polynomial of second order for

$$f(x,y)=\sin(x-\cos(y)), (x_0,y_0)=(1,0)$$

I have already calculated it and I got $T_2(x,y)=x-1+\frac{y^2}{2}$, now I need to give an estimation for the remainder for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ which fulfill $||(x,y)^{T}-(1,0)^{T}|| \leq \frac{1}{2} $. But I do not know how to achieve that?

I have calculated all the third-degree partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial^{3} f(x,y)}{\partial x^3}=-cos(x-cos(y))$$

$$\frac{\partial^{3} f(x,y)}{\partial y^3} = -sin(y)((sin^2(y)+1)cos(x-cos(y))+3cos(y)sin(x-cos(y)))$$

$$\frac{\partial^{3} f(x,y)}{\partial  y^2 \partial x} = sin^2(y)(-cos(x-cos(y)))-cos(y)sin(x-cos(y))$$

$$\frac{\partial^{3} f(x,y)}{\partial  x^2 \partial y} = sin(y)(-cos(x-cos(y)))$$

all the $sin(..)$ and $cos(..)$ have $1$ as upper bound, but how can I find those $(x,y)$ for which $||(x,y)^{T}-(1,0)^{T}|| \leq \frac{1}{2} $. I am having difficulties to use the derivatives in the multivariate remainder formula $R(x,y)$

Comment: Remember the expression for the remainder given in the Taylor Theorem, then try to find an upper bound for that if $||(x,y)-(1,0)||\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @TonyK the Taylor polynomial is centered at $(1,0)$, and $T_2(1,0)=0$, which (a priori) seems right.

Comment: @SamuelM.A.Luque: I only know the formula for the on dimensional case, how to do it in the multivariate case?

Comment: @Parinn https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf

Comment: @SamuelM.A.Luque: which version would I have to use here? the integral version or the Lagrange form?

Comment: @Parinn I would suggest the Lagrange form, for sure